# is it possible to extracting text inside colored background region using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I having the following table area from the original image:

[image]

I'm trying extract the text,from this table.But when using threshold the whole gray regions get darkening.For example like below,

[image]

The threshold type which i did used,

```
thresh_value = cv2.threshold(original_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV +cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

is it possible to extract and change gray background into white and lets remain text pixel as it is if black then?

Comment: Do you want to read the text ( using OCR ), or just extract the region containing the text?

Comment: Hi @GaneshTata, i want to read the text using OCR in here,because i already done in the scenario like any background color with white color text using threshold & morphology detection method. But this process affecting the image  like as mentioned in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use adaptive thresholding in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("text_table.jpg")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# do adaptive threshold on gray image
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 11)

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("text_table_thresh.jpg", thresh)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: thanks for your support .I will check and update the result